# RSpec error User must exist with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm creating some test to test a controller and model. When I use FactoryGirl to create fake data I'm getting errors that the User (which the record belongs to) does not exist.

Here is my model composition.rb

```
class Composition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}

end
```

Here is my FactoryGirl file composition.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :composition do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    description { Faker::Lorem.words }
    import_composition { Faker::Boolean.boolean }
    import_composition_file { Faker::File.file_name('path/to') }
  end
end
```

This is my the RSpec test that I have until this far

```
require 'rails_helper'

  describe CompositionsController do

    before(:each) do
       @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
       @group = FactoryGirl.create(:group)
       sign_in @user
       @composition = Composition.new(FactoryGirl.create(:composition), user_id: @user.id, group_id: @group.id)
    end

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index

      expect(assigns(:composition).to eq(@composition))
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end

end
```

Right now I'm getting an error: **Validation failed: User must exist, Group must exist**

When I don't user FactoryGirl to create a record everything works fine.

Does any body have an suggestion why it's failing?

Comment: ```@composition = FactoryGirl.create(:composition, user_id: @user.id, group_id: @group.id)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass FactoryGirl as a param to Model

```
@composition = FactoryGirl.create(:composition, user: @user, group: @group)
```

If you don't want to create the record but just want it to initialize, use `build` instead of `create`

```
@composition = FactoryGirl.build(:composition, user: @user, group: @group)
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue. It's running now. All tests have passed

Answer (score 0):

something of your dependecies is breaking the model of user thats why user is not being created, you need to specify what is the primary_key again:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'id'
end
```